# How to execute IndexPage Hook Contao

Tags: indexing, content-management-system, contao

I need to remove query parameters from the indexed Url's . For that I wrote IndexPage hook in my extension. When I click on the rebuild index , It is not entering into my hook. How To execute the hook?

config.php

```
$GLOBALS['TL_HOOKS']['indexPage'][] = array('MyExtension\SearchIndex', 'myIndexPage');
```

---

SearchIndex.php

```
<?php
namespace MyExtension;

use Contao;

class SearchIndex{

    public function myIndexPage($strContent, $arrData, $arrSet) {

        var_dump($strContent);exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: I just registered a hook in config file and wrote a custom function to print the generated urls.I updated the question.

Comment: Are you doing this in Contao 3 or Contao 4? In Contao 4 you might not see any output from your `var_dump($strContent);exit;` because that hook is executed in the `kernel.terminate` event.

Comment: Version 4.5.8 . So how can I see the reults and process them?

Comment: Where can I call $kernel->terminate($request, $response); method ? Is this a right method to call this function in any of the extension???

Comment: No, this is something that is executed by the Symfony framework (or the `app.php` in particular). You could try logging instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172036/discussion-between-aswathy-s-and-fritzmg).